# How do I remove mold from a vacuum cleaner?

Tags: cleaning, vacuum

I returned home a couple of weeks ago, only to find my Dyson V6 Slim Cordless Vacuum has been filled up with mold.

It looks like the mold has reached back in towards the engine area:
[image]

I'm wondering if the vacuum cleaner is salvageable - is there anything I can do to clean it properly, and make sure that no mold makes gets spread across my house?

Comment: If it's easy to clean, use a rag and bleach solution. If it's near electrical items and out of warranty, and you feel skilled enough to tackle a diy repair, remove the parts and soak the plastic in a bleach solution. If in warranty or you don't feel skilled enough, take it to a vacuum shop to be cleaned, or replace the vacuum.